# React native Bluetooth keyboard support

Tags: javascript, react-native, bluetooth

I have a react native app and I am trying to see how I can support a Bluetooth keyboard for iPads.  Right now, what it is doing is acting like it is typing something but nothing appears on the text input.  I am assuming this is because react native doesn’t support right off the bat?

Answer (score 0):

In the react-native-keyevent documentation there is a piece of code that needs to be inserted into your AppDeligate file, I had to change it a little in the for loop, after that the event began to come to the keyDownListener

```
for (NSString* names in namesArray) {
     NSRange  range = [names rangeOfCharacterFromSet:validChars];

    [keys addObject: [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:names modifierFlags:0 action:@selector(keyInput:)]];

}
```